# How to use IApplicationBuilder middleware overload in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, middleware, asp.net-core-middleware

ASP.NET Core provides two overloads for `app.Use()` method. Usually we use only one overload that is

```
app.Use(Func<HttpContext,Func<Task>, Task> middleware)
```

Which is used as

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("1st middleware <br/>");
    await next.Invoke();
});
```

The other overload that i want to use is

```
app.Use(Func<RequestDelegate,RequestDelegate> middleware)
```

I couldn't find an example of how we can use this overload. Any ideas will be great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate>` is a delegate, which accepts a delegate and returns a delegate. You can use it with this lambda expression:

```
app.Use(next => async context => 
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello, World!");
    await next(context);
}
```

Comment: `Func<T,TResult>` is a delegate not a lambda, though it **can** be **expressed** as Lambda (also called arrow function). But it can as well be expressed as delegate: `delegate(HttpContext context) { ...}`, or by passing/assigning an Method.