# IApplicationBuilder middleware - why two use overloads?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm trying to figure out the use cases for the two `app.Use()` methods in IApplicationBuilder.

```
app.Use(Func<HttpContext,Func<Task>, Task> middleware)
```

vs

```
app.Use(Func<RequestDelegate,RequestDelegate> middleware)
```

[How to use IApplicationBuilder middleware overload in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42898530/how-to-use-iapplicationbuilder-middleware-overload-in-asp-net-core) answers **how** to use them, but I would like to know **why** you would use one over the other.

Comment: Isn't this just the sync vs async choice?  Which would depend on what you are doing in your actions.

Comment: The first one is more convenient to write anonymous inline lamdas for. The second is the lowest common denominator, it can do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IApplicationBuilder` interface defines only

```
IApplicationBuilder Use(Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate> middleware)
```

second is just [an extension method](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/Extensions/UseExtensions.cs) that allows

> Adds a middleware delegate defined in-line to the application's request pipeline.

and calls `IApplicationBuilder.Use` internally:

```
    public static IApplicationBuilder Use(this IApplicationBuilder app, Func<HttpContext, Func<Task>, Task> middleware)
    {
        return app.Use(next =>
        {
            return context =>
            {
                Func<Task> simpleNext = () => next(context);
                return middleware(context, simpleNext);
            };
        });
    }
```

Comment: After staring at this for an hour I finally got what `Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate>` meant. It's supposed to be a "`RequestDelegate` transformer" that takes an existing `RequestDelegate` and returns another `RequestDelegate` that when called, calls the `middleware` that you are registering while providing your `middleware` a `next` middleware to call. To be honest, the newer overload they've added `Use(IApplicationBuilder, Func<HttpContext, RequestDelegate, Task>)` made much more sense because you have to pass the `context` to `next` yourself, instead of calling a `next` delegate...

Comment: ...that takes no arguments and suddenly the next middleware magically has a `context` to use despite the fact that you never gave it one(the magic is the line `Func<Task> simpleNext = () => next(context);`).

Comment: To be clear, what `Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate>` does is that you get passed the next middleware, and you are supposed to incorporate that into your current middleware, and then return the whole thing. This design is really weird and confusing, and again, it would have made much more sense if the newer extension overload signature were the one in `IApplicationBuilder`.