# What is the purpose of using delegate as parameter for Func in IApplicationBuilder Use(Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate> middleware)

Tags: c#, .net-core

In .NetCore we have IApplicationBuilder interface expose the below method used for configuring middleware

```
IApplicationBuilder Use(Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate> middleware)
```

RequestDelegate inturn represents a delegate

```
public delegate Task RequestDelegate(HttpContext context)
```

What is the purpose of using Func with delegate as parameter. Wouldnt the below implementation of Use method suffice ? or I'm I missing something here

```
IApplicationBuilder Use(RequestDelegate delegateVariableName)
```

Comment: Check below link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42898530/how-to-use-iapplicationbuilder-middleware-overload-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 1):

One of the key points of .Net Core middleware is that you can *'short-circuit'* overall pipeline execution, so, each middleware has an opportunity to invoke the next middleware (some kind of "wrapping" this execution in `RequestDelegate`), or go back. That's why you need `Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate>`, which is something like `app.Use(next => async context => { })`, as pointed by @PrabhatSinha in the comments.

Here how it is going:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        // Do something before next middleware
        if (someDecision) // decision if we will run next
        {
            await next.Invoke(); // next middleware
            // Do something after next middleware
        }
    });
```

Just using `Use(RequestDelegate delegateVariableName)` is not enough. You may read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/). This is very good article.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.